# Drupal_get_form displaying 'Array'

Tags: php, drupal-7

I am working in Drupal 7, and had to make an edit to a pre-existing module.  The module was set to display a form if a certain variable was set to true.   I had to add 3 additional variables, and now instead of showing the form, I see 'Array'. I didn't change anything other than the logic in the if/else to determine if the form should be pulled.

I found a similar problem, that was never answered here ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130535/drupal-7-renderdrupal-get-formform-not-working )

My code is as such:

```
<?php

/**
 * @todo Please document this function.
 * @see http://drupal.org/node/1354
 */
function du_r2t4_block_confirm_view() {

    $provider = du_r2t4_get_provider();
    //drupal_set_message("<pre>provider: ".var_export($provider,TRUE)."</pre>");

    $term = $provider->getCurrentTerm();
    //drupal_set_message("<pre>term: ".var_export($term,TRUE)."</pre>");
    if(!$term) return du_r2t4_get_msg_wrapped("no_term");

    global $user;
    $person = $provider->getPerson($user->name, ($term ? $term->code : NULL));
    //$person->termCode = NULL;
    //$person->satisfied = TRUE;
    //$person->satisfied = FALSE;
    //$person->satisfied = NULL;
    //drupal_set_message("<pre>person: ".var_export($person,TRUE)."</pre>");

    $enrollment = $provider->getEnrollment($person->username, $term->code);
    //$enrollment = array();
    //drupal_set_message("<pre>enrollment: ".var_export($enrollment,TRUE)."</pre>");

    $registered = $term->code && $term->code == $person->termCode && !empty($enrollment);

    if(!$registered) return du_r2t4_get_msg_wrapped("no_reg");

    $content = "";

    if($person->satisfied === TRUE) $content .= du_r2t4_get_msg_wrapped("satisfied");
    elseif($person->satisfied === FALSE) $content .= du_r2t4_get_msg_wrapped("required");
    else $content .= du_r2t4_get_msg_wrapped("unknown");

    $confirmed = $provider->getLastConfirmation($person);
    if($confirmed) $content .= du_r2t4_get_msg_wrapped("confirmed");

    /*
     * TODO move details to form builder
     */

    $content .= "<table style=\"width:auto;\"><tbody style=\"border:0;\">";
    $content .= "<tr><td valign=\"top\">Name:</td><td valign=\"top\">{$person->firstName} {$person->lastName}</td></tr>";
    $content .= "<tr><td valign=\"top\">Id:</td><td valign=\"top\">{$person->identity}</td></tr>";
    $content .= "<tr><td valign=\"top\">Term:</td><td valign=\"top\">{$term->description}</td></tr>";
    $content .= "<tr><td valign=\"top\">Classes:</td><td valign=\"top\">";
    /**
    * Session 2
    */
    $se2 = FALSE;
    $s4e = FALSE;
    $s4m = FALSE;
    $s4l = FALSE; 

    /**
    *
    * Session 2
    *
    */

    foreach ($enrollment as $k => $v) {
    switch ($v->sessionCode){
        case "SE2":
        $se2 = TRUE;
        $content .= $v->crn ." ". $v->subjectCode.$v->courseNumber  ." ".$v->courseTitle ." (" . $v->sessionDescription.")<br />";
        break;

        case "S4E":
        $s4e = TRUE;
        $content .= $v->crn ." ". $v->subjectCode.$v->courseNumber  ." ".$v->courseTitle ." (" . $v->sessionDescription.")<br />";
        break;

        case "S4M":
        $s4m = TRUE;
        $content .= $v->crn ." ". $v->subjectCode.$v->courseNumber  ." ".$v->courseTitle ." (" . $v->sessionDescription.")<br />";
        break;

        case "S4L":
        $s4l = TRUE;
        $content .= $v->crn ." ". $v->subjectCode.$v->courseNumber  ." ".$v->courseTitle ." (" . $v->sessionDescription.")<br />";
        break;

        default:
        $content .= "You're not enrolled in any classes.";
    }
    }

    $content .= "</td></tr>";
    $content .= "</table>";

    //if($_SESSION["du_r2t4_success"]) $content .= "<p>You have intent to attend confirmation has been submitted.</p>";
    //else $content .= drupal_get_form("du_r2t4_form_confirm",$term,$person);

    $content .= "<p>".du_r2t4_get_form_confirm_precontent()."</p>";

    //if(!$se2 || !$s4e || !$s4m || !$s4l || $_SESSION["du_r2t4_success"]) $_SESSION["du_r2t4_success"] = false;
    //else $content .= drupal_get_form("du_r2t4_form_confirm",$term,$person,$enrollment);
    //

    if ($se2 || $s4e  || $s4m  || $s4l  || !$_SESSION["du_r2t4_success"]) 
    {
        $content .= drupal_get_form("du_r2t4_form_confirm",$term,$person,$enrollment);
    }
    else 
    {
        $_SESSION["du_r2t4_success"] = false;
    }


    //$content .= drupal_get_form("du_r2t4_form_confirm",$term,$person);

    return $content;

}
```

The section that isn't working correctly is:

```
if ($se2 || $s4e  || $s4m  || $s4l  || !$_SESSION["du_r2t4_success"]) 
        {
            $content .= drupal_get_form("du_r2t4_form_confirm",$term,$person,$enrollment);
        }
        else 
        {
            $_SESSION["du_r2t4_success"] = false;
        }
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All [drupal_get_form](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_get_form/7) does is turn your form array into something [renderable](https://www.drupal.org/node/930760). If you want your form to be displayed as HTML, you should try something like:

```
<?php

$form = drupal_get_form(...);
$content .= drupal_render($form);

?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!   I got the page to display earlier today by using drupal_render